# trying to delete file but its not working

Tags: python

I tried to delete a file but it just does the else statement even though the file exists.

I also tried to delete other files, but I got same result.

Here is the code:

```py
def deletees():
    if os.path.exists("C:\X-Folder\plugins\autorun"):
        shutil.rmtree("C:\X-Folder\plugins\autorun")
    else:
        print("error: does not exists")

deletees()
```

Comment: Use a raw string, escape the backslashes, or use forward slashes. `\a` is an escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to remove a single file:

```
os.remove(r"C:\X-Folder\plugins\autorun")
# or 
os.remove("C:\\X-Folder\\plugins\\autorun")
```

If you are trying to remove a directory or directory tree:

```
shutil.rmtree(r"C:\X-Folder\plugins\autorun")
# or 
shutil.rmtree("C:\\X-Folder\\plugins\\autorun")
```

> Notice that a raw(`r`) string is used so that `\` characters aren't escaped.

So your specific example would look like this:

- Uncomment the line that is most appropriate for your situation.

```
def deletees():
    if os.path.exists("C:\\X-Folder\\plugins\\autorun"):
        shutil.rmtree("C:\\X-Folder\\plugins\\autorun")  # uncomment me for a directory
        # os.remove("C:\\X-Folder\\plugins\\autorun")      # uncomment me for a file
    else:
        print("error: does not exists")
deletees()
```

---

Finally there is also `os.rmdir` and `os.removedirs` but they only work on empty directories and I would not recommend using either of them.

Comment: yes I know but when I run my code it does the else statement even tho the file exists

Comment: @SWE_PewPew did you try fixing your strings?  If you did then please update them in the question

Comment: wdym with fixing the strings? I'm trying to delete a directory but I want to check if the file is there if not it should print "error: does not exists"

Comment: @SWE_PewPew is `autorun` a directory or a file?

Comment: @BeRT2me it's a folder

Comment: @SWE_PewPew  Copy and paste my version of the code and see if that works

Comment: Hey I did still gets the "error: does not exists"

Comment: What is the output of `os.path.isdir("C:\\X-Folder\\plugins\\autorun")`?

Comment: @SWE_PewPew Also double check the path... make sure its not `X--Folder` or `plugin` or something like that  also make sure the root drive is in fact `C:`

Comment: yup its the right path no idea why its not working super strange I also tried doing it with a bunch of other files but its always the same issue

Comment: @SWE_PewPew   try `shutil.rmtree('C:\\X-Folder\\plugins\\autorun')`  by itself.  not in the function at all.  and then put the error message in your question

Comment: @BeRT2me it's just doing the else statement even tho the file exists the problem is not that its not deleting the problem is that its always doing the else statement

Comment: Okay then try this `os.listdir("C:\\X-Folder\\plugins")`  and make sure autorun is in the output

Comment: What tool are you using to do all this, just a terminal, a jupyter notebook, some IDE with a `.py` file, importing a `.py` file into a notebook, or?

Comment: @BeRT2me I'm using pycharm

Comment: @SWE_PewPew  Try opening up a python shell copy and paste the version that Is in my answer into the shell.  If that works than it is something funky with your pycharm configuration

Comment: @SWE_PewPew Delete your `__pycache__` folder and triple check that you're saving the changes before running's Alexander's version of the code.

Comment: @Alexander & BeRT2me tysm got it to work it was something wrong with my pycharm I'll use visual studio from now on

Comment: @SWE_PewPew glad you figured it out